# How to prevent Heroku clock dyno from sleeping on free tier?

Tags: python, django, heroku, cron, apscheduler

I am using Heroku to host a Django web app. This is just for a fun project that will make no money so paying for the premium service would not make sense.

I am using APScheduler to run a cron job once per day. So for this, I have a clock dyno running. The issue is that the clock dyno keeps going idle after 30mins of inactivity. I read that you can ping the app to keep it from idling but unfortunately, this just keeps the web dyno from idling, the clock dyno still idles.

Any recommendations?

I'm essentially looking for a free way to send scheduled emails once a day. I tried using mailchimp but you have to pay to schedule an email.

Comment: Why not use https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler instead of a dyno just for a cron?

Comment: "This is just for a fun project that will make no money so paying for the premium service would not make sense"—it makes sense if you want to use paid features.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's a good shout, will have to give that a try. Thanks for the suggestion 

Answer (score 1):

Okay so it looks like my original solution does actually work, the issue was with the timezone that was set for the cron job.

There is a service to ping your app to keep it from idling called keffeine.
http://kaffeine.herokuapp.com/